# Как удалить все медиафайлы wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Для плагина нужно сделать функцию очистки бд.
Сделал удаление постов:

```
        $q = new WP_Query( ['posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post' ] );
        if($q->have_posts())
            while($q->have_posts()){
                $q->the_post();
                wp_delete_post($q->post->ID, true);
            }
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Но при этом медиафайлы остаются.
Есть функция `wp_delete_attachment()`, но не знаю как получить `id` всех хранящихся в бд медиафайлов.

Comment: [Велосипедистам](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/wp+reset/)

Comment: мне не нужны сторонние плагины. нужно свое =)

Comment: А велосипедная религия  [код](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-reset/tags/1.4.1) "сторонних" не позволяет смотреть?

Comment: ну дык там удаляется все через drop table. мне такое не надо. мне только медиафайлы и посты. а все остальное оставить

Comment: Вопрос - какие медиафайлы? Прикрепленные к постам - можно. А используемые в постах - надо контент парсить.

Comment: "все остальное оставить" != "нужно сделать функцию очистки бд". Нужно как-то определяться что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($attachments = get_posts(['post_type' => 'attachment','numberposts' => -1,'post_status' => null]))
            foreach($attachments as $attachment)
                    wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true );
```

все просто и без танцев с бубнами

Comment: Так вы грохнули вообще все картинки в базе, в том числе и не относящиеся к удаленным постам.

Comment: @KAGGDesign а доки почитать? https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts Делайте выборку по нужным вам критериям.

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft вы не поняли мой коммент совсем. Мой комментарий означает: "ответ плохой". Автор ответа должен сам править свой ответ или удалить его.

Comment: @KAGGDesign всё я правильно понял. Направление дали верное. Осталось только доработать до идеала. Но это уже нужно смотреть в основном контексте конкретного случая

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft ну а если вы все правильно поняли, то не надо предлагать мне читать документацию. Вы наберите сначала одну десятую моей репутации здесь, а потом выходите с подобными предложениями.